# Is there a Windows 7 program that allows images in a folder to be sorted by how visually similar they look?

Tags: windows, windows-7, images

I'm aware there are tons of programs that allow you to search a given folder for duplicate images and delete them, but are there any [programs/extensions/executables] that will function as an extension of Windows Explorer itself and allow me to sort my pictures by how visually-similar they are, so that I can then use Explorer to browse them and choose whether or not to delete the duplicates?

Thanks, I would really appreciate an answer to this.

Comment: There are many with facial recognition (Picassa, ...) and I know that Facebook has a kick ass recognition algorithm, but I'm not aware of any that could be installed on the desktop

Comment: You have a tough time defining visually similar.  Even Google doesn't do this well.

Comment: @SherwoodBotsford How so? I was under the impression image recognition algorithms are sufficiently mature nowadays. Is this not the case? I know Facebook's is advanced enough to more or less accurately determine the contents of an image, which it uses to automatically generate alt text. Relative to that, defining by colour seems like it should be a lot simpler.

Comment: Try this:  Find an interesting image.  Drag it into the search bar on google.  If you ask it find all sizes, it's pretty good.  But down a couple lines there's a find similar images.  I did this orginially searching for mountains and meadow.  Google guessed "Teletubbies have kids"  when I clicked show similar that's what I got.

Comment: @SherwoodBotsford You’ve misunderstood this question.

Comment: Possibly.  I'm saying that based on present state of the art it isn't possible.  Finding versions that differ in terms of resolution seems to work, but finding 'similar' is a lot more open ended.  Is a black and white version similar?  How about increased/decreased brightness, contrast, or saturation?  How about a 10% crop.  A 50% crop?  One that just has one person photoshopped out?  Flipped right for left?  One with 20% of the image with another face composited in?

Comment: This is a quite old question with no answers yet. Is it really necessary to have this as a plugin for Windows Explorer? If I were asked to write such a tool, I'd try it, but definitely not as a Windows Explorer plugin. You really want the result  in 2 dimensions and it's not possible to tell Explorer on how to sort in 2 dimensions. It depends on the size of the Window and the size of the previews. So, in short, being a programmer, I say that it's unlikely that you'll get it in that way.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at applications based on Clarifai's imgsort API? It's the basis for quite a number of very effective enterprise level image sorting/blocking/detecting applications.

https://blog.clarifai.com/clarifai-featured-hack-automatically-organize-photos-on-your-computer-into-different-folders-with-imgsort

There are many java and python apps doing one type of sort or another and many are free and available on github.

https://github.com/search?q=imgsort